# Can I have different headers for php code?

Tags: php

Can I set first header as ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *") then switch to header("HTTP/1.1" . $errCode . $errMsg) if an error comes up before kill() the page?

My code current look like this:

```
<?php
    header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // other things go here


    function handleError ($errMsg, $errCode) {
        header("HTTP/1.1" . $errCode . $errMsg);
        die();
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
In your case, both headers will be sent.

But remember that no output should be sent before you call `header()` in your error handler.